# Minimize user defined function

Tags: programming

I have a user defined function h[i_,j_] and I would like to find its minimum value over all integers $1 \leq i \leq 100$ and $1 \leq j \leq 100$ and $j \leq i$.  I  would just like Mathematica to try all the possibilities rather than attempt any symbolic minimization. How can you do that?

Comment: Have a look at `Table`.

Comment: Absolutely this way of minimization is not good. because if h take a lot of calculation you must evaluate all of them. i think its better to write your own numerical procedure minimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like loops, you could just go through all combinations and memorize the minimum value and position:

```
h[x_, y_] := ((x - 30)^2 + (y - 10)^2);

min = h[1, 1];
pos = {1, 1};
Do[If[h[i, j] < min, min = h[i, j]; pos = {i, j}], {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
```

And then `min` is 0 and `pos` is `{30,10}` as expected. With this approach you don't need to allocate the memory as in the `Table` example.

Not so fast for this specific example but definitely more beautiful is using `Minimize` although you don't wanted this

```
Minimize[{h[x, y], 1 <= x <= 100 && 1 <= y <= 100}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with Minimize is that it doesn't do anything in my case.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, `Table` can be used to generate the matrix. To find the `{i,j}` pair corresponding to the minimum value, a combination of `Min` and `Position` can be used.

```
tbl = Table[h[i, j], {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, i}];
Position[tbl, Min@tbl, {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to find the parameters, but only the minimum value, you could save memory by finding the minimum for each row. Compare:

```
h[x_, y_] := ((x - 30)^2 + (y - 10)^2);
n = 1500;
Min @ Table[Min @ Array[h[i, #] &, i], {i, n}]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 0
>
> 15405976
> ```

```
Min @ Table[h[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i}];

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 162985456
> ```